# MySQL second highest in each project

Tags: mysql, highest

I want to calculate the SECOND highest `hourly_rate` of employee in each project.
But I don't know where I am doing wrong

My concerned table structure:

```
project_team: project_code (FK), employee_id (FK), hourly_rate
```

this is my query which gives the only one record that too isn't second highest.

NOTE: I have 3 projects and each project has many employees.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM project_team GROUP BY project_code ORDER BY hourly_rate DESC LIMIT 1,1
) e;
```

Comment: Why do you have a sub-select there? You don't need it

Comment: First,I wanted to select 3 projects with second highest hour_rate and then have view of those... Why I don't need sub-select query?

Comment: It returns my one project with the highest hourly_rate.

Comment: what if there IS no second highest? ie, they're all equal, OR there's only one employee?

Comment: You are right Cristik with just one more requirement that I want second highest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joins` aren't limited to equality, you can also join on `<`. This means if we find the `max(hourly_rate)` we can then join to that result based on all `hourly_rate` that is less than the `max`, and that also has the same `project_code`, from there we just have to group again and get the `max` value from the joined table.

```
select p1.project_code, max(p2.hourly_rate)
from
 (select project_code, max(hourly_rate) r from project_team group by project_code) p1
 left join project_team p2
   on p2.project_code = p1.project_code and p2.hourly_rate < p1.r
group by project_code;
```

(this assumes there is always a second highest (either all employees have same rate, or only one employee))

```
select p1.project_code, ifnull(max(p2.hourly_rate), p1.r) 
from
 (select project_code, max(hourly_rate) r from project_team group by project_code) p1
 left join project_team p2
   on p2.project_code = p1.project_code and p2.hourly_rate < p1.r
group by project_code;
```

And this one will give the highest value, if there is no second highest.

[Demo Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/976f0/7)

```
select t.project_code, t.second_max_rate, t2.employee_id
from
  (select p1.project_code, ifnull(max(p2.hourly_rate), p1.r)  second_max_rate
    from
     (select project_code, max(hourly_rate) r from project_team group by project_code) p1
    left join project_team p2
      on p2.project_code = p1.project_code and p2.hourly_rate < p1.r
  group by project_code) t
  inner join project_team t2
    on t.project_code = t2.project_code and t.second_max_rate = t2.hourly_rate
  group by t.project_code;
```

This version also includes employee - take note however that it abuses mysqls leniancy with respect to `group by`, you will get AN employee, but there's no guarantee about which one you will get if there are multiple with the same rate.

Comment: Worked!
Now let's assume if there is no second highest.

Comment: I am unable to get accurate employee_id for the second highest hourly_rate @pala_

Comment: sorry, didnt realise you wanted the employee as well

Comment: It's ok, I couldn't do myself.

Comment: Last Question! Can you refer me a good resource where I can understand MySQL quiet deeply and with solid explanation?

Comment: i cant think of one off the top of my head. honestly just practicing and understanding what other people show you is the best way to go. I also updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75466/discussion-between-imam-bux-and-pala).